# Case statement to determine if I should union

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, case, union

I currently want to do some sort of conditional union. Given the following example:

```
SELECT  age, name
FROM    users
UNION
SELECT  25 AS age, 'Betty' AS name
```

Say I wanted to only union the second statement if the count of 'users' was >=2 , otherwise do not union the two.

In summary I want to append a table with a row if the table only has 2 or more values.

Comment: Btw, use `UNION ALL` if you don't want to eliminate duplicates, it's more efficient.

Comment: Is it a stored-procedure or a table-valued function or a plain query?

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* - it has to yield a single scalar value (per row, if part of a result set).

Comment: This is actually a subquery...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use <strike>an ugly hack</strike> something like this, but I think [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30327097/3094533) is better:

```
SELECT  age, name
FROM    users
UNION ALL

SELECT  25, 'Betty'
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users) > 1;
```

Comment: Why are you using top 1 and the users table in the second query? Just remove the table and the top 1 since you are just selecting constants.

Comment: Done, I just thought about it as a quick hack, and after a second thought I realized I can do that without the from

Comment: why "ugly hack"? it states in pure sql exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: This isn't a hack and it produces what the OP wants.

Comment: It just doesn't *feel right* to me. I would go with the if...else since it's more readable.

Comment: Ok, Ok, I've caved in to peer pressure and rephrased my answer.

Comment: sql is a declarative language, the engine executes your queries in the best manner it finds. doing things procedurally you may prevent the engine finding the best way to do it (in general, may not apply to this case).

Comment: This is a good cross-platform solution, except for the missing semicolon at the end, which even Microsoft encourages. Also, don’t bother with the aliases in the second `SELECT`, as only the names for the first `SELECT` are used anyway. Now for the bad news: according to SSMS, this takes _three_ times as long as using the `IF … ELSE` solution.

Comment: @Manngo Feel free to upvote Tim's answer (with the if...else solution) and edit in the missing semicolon.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Philosophically I prefer this solution. I use a variation of this for default values, but unioning a search row with a default row for when the search row doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 10):

If it's in a stored-procedure you could use `If...Else`:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users) < 2
 BEGIN
  SELECT  age, name
  FROM    users
  END
ELSE
  SELECT  age, name
  FROM    users
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  25 AS age, 'Betty' AS name
```

Otherwise you could try something like this:

```
SELECT  age, name
  FROM    users
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  TOP 1 25 AS age, 'Betty' AS name
  FROM users
  WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users) >= 2
```

Note that i've used `UNION ALL` since it doesn't seem that you want to eliminate duplicates.

Played around here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7540/2323/0

**Edit**: Instead of my second approach i prefer [Zohar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30327171/284240). So if you can use `If....Else` prefer that otherwise `WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users) > 1` without a table.

Comment: in your second query, SELECT 'Betty' FROM users will multiply Betty by # of users.

Comment: @1010: No,why? I have used `TOP 1`. But that's the reason why i've mentioned that i prefer Zohars approach.

Comment: Why the top 1? Would be easier to remove the top 1 and the users table since it is just selecting constants.

Comment: @SeanLange: yes of course, that's why Zohars approach is easier and better, it just didn't come into my mind in the first place. I keep it since it's working.

Comment: @TimSchmelter oh, I'm sorry... missed that part

Answer (score 6):

Something like the following should work:

```
SELECT  age, name
FROM    users

UNION ALL

SELECT age, name
FROM (SELECT  25 AS age, 'Betty' AS name) x
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users) y(cnt)
WHERE y.cnt >= 2
```

Second part of `UNION ALL` will be `NULL` in case `users` table has less than 2 records.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT age
     , name
FROM   users

UNION

SELECT 25 As age
     , 'Betty' As name
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT Count(*)
         FROM   users
         HAVING Count(*) >= 2
       )
;
```